# The peak throughput of cuda Kernel on NVIDA GPU

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have a question about the throughput of a kernel running on a GPU. Assuming its occupancy is 0.5, block size is 256: the programming guide states that it is better to have many blocks so they can hide the memory latency, etc. But I don't understand why this is correct. Because as soon as the kernel has a number of warp per Streaming Multi-processor = 24, i.e., 3 blocks, it will reach the peak throughput. So having more than 24 warps (or 3 blocks) won't change anything to the throughput.

Am I missing anything? Can anyone correct me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is true that low occupancy SMs cannot sufficiently hide latency, it is important to understand this:

Higher Occupancy != Higher Throughput!

Occupancy is simply a measure of how much work is available for the SM to choose from at any given instant.  Having more resident warps gives the SM more ability to do useful work while other warps are waiting for results (results of memory accesses, or computations -- both have non-zero latency).

Throughput is a measure of how much work gets done per second, and while it can be limited by latency (and therefore occupancy), it also can be limited by memory bandwidth, instruction throughput (the number of execution units), and other factors.

The reason the programming guide states that it is better to have multiple thread blocks than just one large thread block is because sometimes it is better to be able to issue work from not just other warps but also other blocks.  Here's an example:

Imagine that your big thread block has to load data from global memory (high latency) and store it in to shared memory (low latency), and then must immediately do a `__syncthreads()`.  In this case, when a warp is finished loading its data and writing it to shared memory, it must then wait until *all other* threads in the block finish doing the same.  For a large block, that can be quite a while.  But if there are multiple smaller thread blocks occupying the SM, then the SM could switch and do work from the other blocks while waiting for the `__syncthreads` to be satisfied in the first block.  This can help reduce GPU idle time and improve efficiency.

You don't necessarily want to have really tiny blocks (since the SMs on Fermi support at most 8 resident blocks), but having blocks of 128-512 threads is often more efficient than using blocks with 1024 threads.

Comment: OK, I got what you say. It is all correct, I believe. But something is missing. Please use my example: occupancy=0.5, blocksize=256. I sense this is common for many kernels. This means I will have 24 active warps (or 3 active blocks) in GTX580. So what is the difference in throughput between launching 3 blocks and 6 blocks? What are the reasons for the difference?

Comment: Higher occupancy != Higher Throughput!  So without knowing specifics about the bottleneck of the kernel, it is impossible to predict the difference in throughput between launching 3 and 6 blocks in general. Now, if occupancy is *limited* to 0.5 (by register or shared mem use), and your GPU has at least 6 SMs, then launching 6 blocks instead of 3 should double your throughput, since this would use more SMs.  Generally you want to launch at least as many blocks as you have SMs, if not multiple per SM.  But I don't think this is what you are asking...

Comment: Oh sorry I'm screwed up. What I wanted to say is 3 blocks PER SM, and 6 block PER SM (not the total number of blocks). Yes I'm pretty sure that it will depends on the bottleneck of the kernel, but how? And there should be some general cases, right? (And assuming the occupancy to be keept at 0.5 - actually it wouldn't be affected by the number of blocks)

Comment: Or to put it simple, let's just say the kernel occupancy is 0.5. This mean I can have 3 active blocks per SM. In the GPU, there are 16 SMs. When I launch 48 blocks in total, the IPC (instruction per cycle) is 100. But when I launch 64 blocks in total, the IPC is 120, what is likely to be the reason for this difference?

Comment: I think you mean 1.0 and 1.2 rather than 100 and 120, but my guess is that there is some skew in the launch times of your blocks, or your blocks have variable run time, so that having more than 48 blocks helps fill in some gaps on SMs after one or more of the initial 3 blocks finish, thus raising overall efficiency.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I've been guessing. Thanks for confirming it. It would look like Lego game I guess..

Answer (score 1):

Having more than 3 blocks won't change the throughput in your case if you have only **one** SM in your cuda-enabled card. Usually you have 8 or more SMs in a single GPU.

Also the number of blocks that will run on one SM is not solely based on the number of warps. That is just one limiting factor, there are many others factors as well. [CUDA Occupancy Calculator](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls) is a great tool to see the occupancy of your kernel.

Comment: So what will it change to the throughput if I have more than one SM in my card? Say 16. I know about Cuda occupancy calculator, but it doesn't help here. What I am asking is "what is the the difference from having enough warps(all you have is active warps) and having more than enough warps(you have some active warps, and the others are idle). I bet the answer wouldn't be that short.